# MS OneNote beginning/end of line shortcuts on Mac

Tags: keyboard, ms-office, shortcut

I am using OneNote on a Mac and the beginning of line and end of line shortcuts are `Ctrl+A` and `Ctrl+E`, respectively. I prefer the alternatives `Fn+<` and `Fn+>` instead, which work in other applications on Mac but not in OneNote for some reason. I tried adding them from `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts`, but looks like you cannot add a shortcut with a `Fn` button there. Any ideas on how to enable using `Fn+<` and `Fn+>` as the beginning of line and end of line shortcuts in OneNote on Mac?

Note: I am using a Mac 2019 with a touchbar that is controlled by the Fn key.

Comment: Fn + arrow key is equivalent to page up/down/home/end on a regular extended keyboard. idk how you would tell an MS app that, but that's what it is.

Comment: Ctrl-A and Ctrl-E are system level.  Normally when you see emacs keyboard shortcuts, they're built-ins.